# Роутинг приложения

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, node.js

У меня router частично, на node ( express ) частично на angular. На определенных страничках сделано Angular приложение (c ui-router). Когда я перережу на станичнику где angular приложение, то не могу выйти потом из нее (Например перейти на главную из магазина (на страничке магазин angular приложение с ui-router)), ссылки не работают.
Код на сервере:

```
router.get('/range', function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('range', {ru : "ru"});
});

router.get('/range/*', function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('range', {ru : "ru"});
});
```

Код Angular

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('application', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])

        .config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                $locationProvider
                    .hashPrefix('!')
                    .html5Mode(true);

                $stateProvider
                    .state('product', {
                        url: '/range',
                        templateUrl: 'app1/views/product.html',
                        controller: 'productCntr'
                    })
                    .state('products', {
                        url: '/range/:id?',
                        templateUrl: 'app1/views/product.html',
                        controller: 'productCntr'
                    })
            }]);
})(angular);
```

Контроллер

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('application')
        .controller('productCntr',
            ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$location',
                function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $location) {

                    var id = $state.params.id || -1;

                    $scope.model = {
                        productId:  id
                    };
                }
            ]);


})(angular);
```

Comment: стоит проверить ссылки по которым идет попытка перейти, но совпадение роутов уже настораживает

Comment: <li><a href="/range">Ассортимент</a></li> Ссылки обычные, они работают если на них переходить с тех страничек где нет Angular приложения

Comment: в ангуляре роут с тем же урл

Comment: то что вы говорите фигня

Comment: что именно из?.

Comment: ставя "в ангуляре роут с тем же урл"

Comment: но ведь там действительно одинаковые урл стоят :-) `range`

Answer (score 1):

Подписаться на ошибку перехода в ангуляре и в обход обёрток установить `window.location.href`.

Answer (score -1):

Это можно сделать ставя ссылки по умолчанию #/  тогда серверная часть не будет конфликтовать c Angular и  наоборот